# Parameterizing closures as generic based on parameter-list/return type

Tags: swift, generics

Is there a way to make a generic type signature for a closure such that I can later call it generically? In particular my question is how to deal with an unknown number of arguments.

I have an object that I’d like to call a series of closures on an update, and I’d like other objects to be able to register closures that they’d like to be called with that first object.

Closures aren’t hashable, but I’d like to be able to also unregister a closure, so I wound up creating a custom type to handle this based on a dictionary:

```
//T is the block signature such as Double->()
struct ClosureCollection<T> : SequenceType {
    private var idx=0
    var closureDict:[Int:(T,NSOperationQueue)]=[:]


    mutating func addClosure(b:T) -> Int {
        return addClosure(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(),b)
    }

    mutating func addClosure(q:NSOperationQueue, _ b:T) -> Int {
        closureDict[idx]=(b,q)
        idx+=1
        return idx-1
    }

    mutating func dropClosure(k:Int) {
        closureDict.removeValueForKey(k)
    }

    func generate() -> AnyGenerator<(T,NSOperationQueue)> {
        var dgen=closureDict.generate()
        return AnyGenerator {
            return dgen.next()?.1
        }
    }
}
```

This lets me use the collection in code like this:

Declare it:

```
private var distributionPoints=ClosureCollection<(CMDeviceMotion?,NSError?) -> ()> ()
```

Use it:

```
for (p,q) in distributionPoints {
    q.addOperationWithBlock {p(dm,error)}
}
```

So far, all’s good but it requires the caller to follow a pretty specific pattern to use the collection that I'd like to hide. I’d like to extend this idea to where I can ask the collection to run the for loop itself using syntax something like

```
distributionPoints.runAllWith(dm,error)
```

The problem is with the runAllWith signature-- my current implementation is generic over the full closure signature because I don't know how to make the number of arguments to the closure generic.  I suspect this can be done if I know the blocks accept one argument and return one argument, for example, by using two type placeholders, say T for the argument and U for the return value.

What I don’t seem able to do is make this generic across an unknown number of parameters.  The type I’m creating doesn’t care what the structure of the block is, it just wants to accept closures with a certain signature and then provide a mechanism to call them by exposing an API that depends on the closure signature.

I don’t think there’s support for variadic generic parameters, so I can’t go down that road.  Tuple-splat was deprecated.

Is there a way to do this without requiring the caller to bundle arguments into a tuple and then requiring a wrapper around each closure to unwrap a tuple of arguments and do a hand-crafted tuple splat?